# Has MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity disappeared?

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to upgrade to MvvmCross 5.2 and get a syntax error on the MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity. Has this class disappeared?

Comment: This class is available in the MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat namespace. It has been installed via Nuget but for some reason is not available. I've tried reinstall of the library but no luck so far

Comment: The object browser in VS2017 reveals the class is not available in the mentioned namespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the blog for 5.2: https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-52-release/

We've refactored the Android presenter and there is no need anymore for a special `Activity` like `MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity`. The adviced `Activity` to use now is the `MvxAppCompatActivity`.

Comment: I did see the explanation in the blog but did not see a remark that this change was breaking the MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity. I'll try to change to the MvxAppCompatActivity.