# Replacing MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity and the Backstack

Tags: mvvmcross

I've been upgrading an MVVMCross project to v5.6.3

Mostly there, but I have a question. I've read and digesting this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339406/540156).

In my old code, which inherited from the `MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity`  class, I had the following method overload:

```
public override void OnBeforeFragmentChanging(IMvxCachedFragmentInfo fragmentInfo, Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction transaction)
{
    var currentFrag = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.content_frame) as MvxFragment;

    if (currentFrag != null && fragmentInfo.ViewModelType != typeof(MenuViewModel)
        && currentFrag.FindAssociatedViewModelType(typeof(MainViewModel)) != fragmentInfo.ViewModelType)
        fragmentInfo.AddToBackStack = true;

    base.OnBeforeFragmentChanging(fragmentInfo, transaction);
}
```

Is this responsibility of adding a fragment to the backstack now handled by MVVMCross? Or is there a replacement method which I am meant to overload?

My observation is that the fragments are being added to the backstack, as evidenced by the previous fragment loading when I tap the back button.

Just wanted clarification on that if possible.

Cheers